# Pass json data to blade view from controller

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am loading a json file from my resources folder resources/data/example.json

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Load json file 
    $path = base_path('resources/data/rooms.json');
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    $data = json_decode($content);
}
```

my json file looks like this, it's a simple one just for an example:`[ { "id":"bicycle", "category":"vehicle", "name":"Bicycle One", "images":[ "/img/bike_slider_1.jpg", "/img/bike_slider_2.jpg" ], },`

so now I am wondering how can I pass some of this data to the view which is e.g bikes.blade.php
which looks like this:
`@extends('layouts.default') @section('content')  <main>{{ content[1] }}</main>`

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    public function index()
    {
        // Load json file 
        $path = base_path('resources/data/rooms.json');
        $content = file_get_contents($path);
        $data = json_decode($content);
    
        return view('bikes', [
                'items' => $data,
            ]);
    }
```

Inside blade

```
@foreach ($items as $item) 
    {{ $item->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views

you can follow this link. You already convert JSON data into object. Now just pass it from controller.

```
return view('yourBladeFile')->with('data ', $data );
```

Now in blade file you can read it like:

```
@foreach($data as $item)
  <p> {{$item->name}} </p>
@endforeach
```

or other suitable way for you.